# React.js and folder access denied for user

Tags: reactjs, file, directory

I don't know if there is any type of post like this one here on StackOverflow but I just wonder how do I make so people who visit my site can't get access to "ip/folder names".

If it for some help I use react.js and I know some people use the `.htaccess` file but it doesn't work for me or maybe because I do it wrong. I am kind of new of this sort of things.

**Error page**

I want actually do so if people visit some page/folder or file they come to a page it says "404 page error"

Comment: This is definitely a configuration issue of the web server. But how to configure it is depending on what kind web server you are using for your site? Apache? Nginx?

Comment: well i using Apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use .htaccess files depends on how the apache configuration is done on your server. A .htaccess file needs permission to be able to override standard web configurations. If you want to set that up and use them you can try:

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

Then make sure the line AllowOverride has the value All. That means local .htaccees files are allowed to override.

```
 <Directory /var/www/>
    ...

    AllowOverride All

    ...
 </Directory>
```

Save and restart the service

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

In your .htaccess file you can add following for creating an custom error page

```
ErrorDocument 404 /my_custom_error_page.html
```

Here you can read more about writing .htaccess files
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file

Hope that helped a bit.

Comment: Yeah. I fixed my .htaccess file so it works right now for me thanks btw for try help me guys! :D –